# How can you convert XPS to PDF using iText library?

Tags: itext, xps

Is it possible to convert a xps document to PDF using iTextSharp library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[One person](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsxps/thread/1917fede-bf5c-4c66-92cd-e97cfa0206cc) recommended turning pdf to an image then transforming that into an xps file. (note that  the current version of itext# seems to AGPL licensed -so your application has to be open source if you use the current version).

Comment: The question is about converting XPS to PDF (not the other way) using iText.